# How to access camera in oracle apex Application Express 20.2.0.00.20

Tags: html5-canvas, oracle-apex, mediadevices

hope you all will be fine ,I am beginner in oracle apex and want to access camera ,
I tried below code in latest oracle apex which worked fine but in oracle apex 20.2.0.00.20 it show following error "Your browser does not support the MediaDevices API." .I want to access camera in oracle apex 20.2.0.00.20 ,how can i do this?
here is the code

```
function startCamera() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
        .then(stream => {
            const videoElement = document.getElementById("videoElement");
            videoElement.srcObject = stream;
            videoElement.play();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error starting camera:", error);
        });
```

note: i am using both apex workspace on same browser

Comment: Have you tried using a 'file browse' item?

Comment: Scott , currently we are uploading image using filebrowse but i want to capture through live camera on region